# Making nested HTTP requests grabbing url from response

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a URL I'm trying to make requests to.

So, I each requests has a dictionary called url and has_more. 
I want to start with a request; and keep making nested requests from dictionary url if the response has_more is true.

dictionary looks like this;

```
dictionary['url'] = someurl
dictionary['has_more']= True


r = requests.get('some_url').json()
url = r['url']#then keep making more nested requests.
```

Issue I'm currently having is:

I do not know the URL of the next request until I get the response JSOn from the before URL.
So; I don't know how that is done exactly in python as running a plain loop wouldn't do the job.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: @Chamath I do not know the URL of the next request until I get the response JSOn from the before URL.
So; I don't know how that is done exactly in python as running a plain loop wouldn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to iterate through a while loop.

```
has_more = True
url = '<your_url>'

while has_more:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_json = response.json()
    if not ('has_more' in response_json and response_json['has_more']):
        # Either you dont have has_more in response or its false
        has_more = False
    else:
        # You can do any other jobs you need to done here if has_more is true
        url = response_json['url']
```

So this loop with go untill you get `has_more=False`.